# My modal gallery doesn't work when implemented to portfolio

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website for a school project and I had made a modal gallery to show some pages of a brochure. So to test I made a seperate document to see if it would work and it did. But ofcourse when I tried to put it in my correct webpage it didn't.

It should be in the blue GIP section but instead it is on the bottom of the page and I can't seem to get it to go up. Also the whole gallery is broken but that is not for this sub I think.

Thank you to anyone that tries to help.

Test: http://www.vseppe.gc-m.be/Gip/test.html

Webpage: http://www.vseppe.gc-m.be/Gip/index.html

I can't figure out how to paste the code correctly in here, please comment or message if you need it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, we need your code here. There is an icon to add a Stack Snippet that looks like this `<>` in the bar above the WYSIWYG. You can add HTML/CSS/JS in the respective boxes.